# How to open a command line window in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line, process

How to open a new command line window and execute a bash command which runs in a separate independent process?

I tried

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execSync("cmd.exe /K node my-new-script.js parm1 parm2);
```

but it opens no new window and I need an independent process (if possible). The background is I am experimenting with electron and wrote some node command line scripts. Unfortunately within electron environment spawning processes results often in weird behavior and console log output is more than ugly.

By the way I would need something equivalent to OS X and Linux.

Comment: You might have to use the `start` command to force open a new Command Prompt window.

Comment: @remus This is exactly what I want. I ever thought I know windows ^^.  Do you coincidentally know equivalents to Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Windows, you'll need to use the `start` command:

```
start cmd.exe /K node my-new-script.js parm1 parm2
```

For OS X, you can use:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

For other *nix distros, you'll need to look those up as each one is slightly different.

Comment: Is there any possibility to run this in background?

Comment: @YD_ Use `child_process.exec()` instead of `child_process.execSync()` to run the terminal in background.