# Nodejs how to create a button that runs a command in cmd and terminal?

Tags: node.js, cmd, terminal, electron

I am looking for a cross platform way between Windows and Mac where I can create a button, that when it is pressed will execute a command in cmd/terminal, if anyone knows how it would be really appreciated if you could let me know thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  I can point you to the child_process module https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html but without knowing more about what you want to do with it, or seeing what code you've tried it's hard to be of much help.

Comment: @generalhenry I want a command prompt to open and execute an exe but also a .pyc file for mac

Comment: Depending on if the user is mac or windows

Comment: Do you want an in app terminal as in https://hyper.is or to open an external terminal

Comment: @generalhenry I want to use an external terminal for example for Windows command prompt

Comment: This answer may have what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737949/1267724