# How to launch cmd by using node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to launch cmd by .js file and automatically type some commands in it?

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const open = require("open");

const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

readline.question("Launch cmd?", async (name) => {
  if (name === "Y") {
    await open("cmd.exe", { wait: true }); //how i can write something in cmd?
  } else {
    process.exit(console.log("You have closed the programm"));
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737743/how-to-open-a-command-line-window-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You can either do something similar as said in this thread.

[How to open a command line window in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737743/how-to-open-a-command-line-window-in-node-js)

```
start cmd.exe /K node my-new-script.js parm1 parm2
```

But if you want to run multiple commands, use a batch script and run that batch script from Nodejs. Batch Scripts are stored in simple text files containing lines with commands that get executed in sequence, one after the other.

```
require('child_process').exec('cmd /c batfile.bat', function(){
   // …you callback code may run here…
});
```

You can learn more about the batch script here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_overview.htm

Comment: Thx. How i can repeat batfile.bat commands x times and repeat opening of batfile.bat?

Comment: You can implement that logic inside js itself.